# How to see if venue is closed via the Foursquare API?

Tags: foursquare

If a venue is closed, there doesn't appear to be a flag in the JSON response from /venues/ so that we can know this venue is closed.

For example, https://foursquare.com/v/bar-breton/4a2edc78f964a52070981fe3 is a closed venue and the foursquare website clearly say it is closed.

However, if you access this venue via the API https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4a2edc78f964a52070981fe3 there does not appear to be any flag or indicator that the venue is closed.

How can we get this information from the API?

Comment: have you tried asking the chaps over at 4Square?

Comment: Hrm, definitely strange. We'll look into it and I'll get back to you. The API response should definitely indicate that the venue is closed.

Answer (score 3):

Starting later today, there will be "closed": true entry in the venue object iff the venue is closed (it will not be present for open venues).